# Adding an object to an array of objects with splice

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
event_id=[{"0":"e1"},{"0","e2"},{"0","e4"}];
```

How do I add an element to that array?

I thought of

```
event_id.splice(1,0,{"0":"e5"});
```

Thanks.

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12189963/984780

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I want to add the object in the middle of the array, I ended with this solution:

```
var add_object = {"0": "e5"};
event_id.splice(n, 0, add_object); // n is declared and is the index where to add the object
```

Comment: what about deleting an object where value = 'e5' ?

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to add a value to the end of an array then the `push(newObj)` function is easiest, although `splice(...)` will also work (just a bit trickier).

```javascript
var event_id = [{"0":"e1"}, {"0":"e2"}, {"0":"e4"}];
event_id.push({"0":"e5"});
//event_id.splice(event_id.length, 0, {"0":"e5"}); // Same as above.
//event_id[event_id.length] = {"0":"e5"}; // Also the same.
event_id; // => [{"0":"e1"}, {"0":"e2"}, {"0":"e4"}, {"0":"e5"}];
```

See the excellent [MDN documentation for the `Array` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for a good reference of the methods and properties available on arrays.

**[Edit]** To insert something into the *middle* of the array then you'll definitely want to use the `splice(index, numToDelete, el1, el2, ..., eln)` method which handles both deleting and inserting arbitrary elements at any position:

```javascript
var a  = ['a', 'b', 'e'];
a.splice( 2,   // At index 2 (where the 'e' is),
          0,   // delete zero elements,
         'c',  // and insert the element 'c',
         'd'); // and the element 'd'.
a; // => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: I'd like to add the object in the middle of the array.

Answer (score 3):

ES6 solution with spread operator:

```
event_id=[{"0":"e1"},{"0","e2"},{"0","e4"}];
event_id = [...event_id,{"0":"e5"}]
```

or if you do not want to mutate event_id

```
newEventId = [...event_id,{"0":"e5"}]
```

**UPDATE**: to insert object after a specific index or object key or object value respectively you can:

```
const arr = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4}]

arr.reduce((list,obj,index)=>index===1 ? [...list,obj,{g:10}] : [...list,obj], [])
arr.reduce((list,obj)=>Object.keys(obj)[0]==='b' ? [...list,obj,{g:10}] : [...list,obj], [])
arr.reduce((list,obj)=>Object.values(obj)[0]===2 ? [...list,obj,{g:10}] : [...list,obj], [])

// output:  [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { g: 10 }, { c: 3 }, { d: 4 } ]
```

Comment: You can't add a object with this method in between of the array of objects. Only start and end will work right

Comment: yes you are right...I just updated the answer for adding object in between of the array

Answer (score 0):

```
event_id.push({"something", "else"});
```

Try using `.push(...)` ^

Comment: The questions states: `event_id=[{"0":"e1"},{"0","e2"},{"0","e4"}];`, which _is_ an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could typically use:

```
event_id[event_id.length] = {"0":"e5"};
```

or (the slightly slower)

```
event_id.push({"0":"e5"});
```

though if you mean to insert an element into the middle of an array and not always on the end, then we'll have to come up with something a bit more creative.

Hope it helps,

ise